# Different code coverage results in TFS for the same commit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tfs, asp.net-core-mvc

I am wondered why code coverage always shows different results. For example, these are different code coverage results for the **same** commit:

[image]

and:

[image]

My configuration settings looks like:

[image]

**I am rerunning the build the same commit in the same branch**

Does somebody know why do code coverage results always different in the **same** commit?

Comment: Do any of your tests use randomly-generated test data?

Comment: @MatthewWatson [AutoFixture](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-coverage) is used to to create objects. But results are always the same, if I run these tests in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Your counts of blocks and lines are very different so I assume the content being built is very different. Is this the 'same' commit but in different branches? Or are you rerunning the build for the same commit in the same branch?

Comment: @JonathanDodds I am rerunning the build the same commit in the same branch

Comment: @Learner Check the code coverage detail. Look at the breakdown by namespace and/or types within namespaces, and find where the block and line counts differ between builds.